# Whats wrong with this Mysql PDO execution that makes it not execute?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, execution

This query is not executing, and I'm sure its going over the code, it just doesn't update the row.

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET data=:data WHERE id=:id");
$statement->execute(array(':data' => $data, ':id' =>     $_REQUEST['user_id']));
```

What could be the problem? I am 100% that the `$_REQUEST['user_id']` is valid and exists in the DB, and that data contains something as well. I'm really clueless why it wont execute.

Comment: How can we know why it doesn't execute? Usually you get an error message, and if you don't then you inspect the parameters that you're passing to the `execute` function. You have `$data` and you have `$_REQUEST['user_id']` being passed. Saying you are sure that something is valid is meaningless unless you verify that your assertions are right - that being that the both variables are set.

Comment: I have verified both contain things with an isset, I mean I'm honestly as clueless as you. No error is given, it just skips over this code like its nothing! Really strange. I mean, at the top of the script, I use this exact same code but in a "SELECT" to receive user data, and it confirmed works:

Comment: @N.B. `$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
 $query->execute(array($_REQUEST['user_id']));`

Comment: Have you tried getting the error message through $statement->errorInfo()? If you have, what does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [binding](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) your params first:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET data=:data WHERE id=:id");

$statement->bindValue(':data', $data, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':id',  $_REQUEST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$statement->execute();
```